# Why do androids hibernate in the Alien movies?

Tags: alien-franchise, artificial-intelligence, alien-1979, aliens-1986

The android, Bishop, in the *Aliens* movie hibernates with the rest of the *Sulaco* crew for the 17 day voyage. **Does he need to sleep?**

Unlike the *Alien* movie where Ash hibernated because was merely pretending to be human, Bishop does not need to pretend. The Weyland-Yutani representative, Carter Burke, implied it is company policy to include an android among the crew.

> BURKE: "It's just common practice. We always have a synthetic on board."

Why did Bishop sleep?

Comment: Curiously, the *Aliens* novelization, presumably based on an earlier version of the screenplay and containing the extra material from the extended cut of the film plus numerous other minor differences and alterations, has Bishop awake during the voyage on the *Sulaco* the same way that David was in *Prometheus*, and Ripley instantly knows he's an android because of a serial number tattooed on his hand. Out of universe, perhaps just a change to more dramatically reveal him as an android to the audience?

Comment: To fit in with the rest of the crew, probably

Comment: Recharge break?

Comment: Perhaps androids are prone to becoming eccentric in the prolonged absence of humans to regularly recalibrate its behaviour against?  It's fairly easy to find different justifications for it.

Comment: To avoid getting bored.

Comment: To dream of electric sheep?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211393/why-is-bishop-in-cryosleep-despite-being-an-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Bishop in cryosleep despite being an android?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211393/why-is-bishop-in-cryosleep-despite-being-an-android)